# Hex to Dec using bit-manipulation

Tags: c++, c, hex, bit-manipulation, converters

Could somebody explain how this actually works for example the `char input = 'a'`.
I understand that << shift the bits over by four places (for more than one character). But why in the second part add 9? I know 0xf = 15.....Am I missing something obvious.

```
result = result << 4 | *str + 9 & 0xf;
```

Here is my understand so far:

char input = 'a' ascii value is 97. Add 9 is 106, 106 in binary is 01101010. 0xf = 15 (00001111), therefore 01101010 & 00001111 = 00001010, this gives the value of 10 and the result is then appended on to result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at the bit patterns produced by the value at `*str` and `9 & 0xf`...

Comment: search for `bit operators` and `c`. note: we could tell you but you have to expend some effort too.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Sorry I have updated the code.

Comment: What are the values of `result` and `*str` on input?

Comment: @KevinDTimm I understand about bitwise AND and OR...I just don't understand the + 9. Ive worked it out on paper, in terms of binary but I just don't understand the code.

Comment: @dbush result is simply 0, while *str is a char so for example 'a'.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Added some working :)

Comment: Code, for converting `'a'` to `'f'` or `'A'` to `'F'` to `10` to `15` could have been `result = result << 4 | (*str -'a' + 10) & 0xf;`.  Does that help? It is the same as `... *str + 9 & 0xf`, only a bit less obfuscated.

Comment: This code is broken and doesn't work for `'0'`...`'9'`. Downvoted for the lack of context in the question.

Comment: Looks like from those dark days when "getting smart" yourself was sometimes necessary due to the lack of proper optimizations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's rewrite this with parenthesis to make the order of operations more clear:

```
result = (result << 4) | ((*str + 9) & 0xf);
```

If `result` is 0 on input, then we have:

```
result = (0 << 4) | ((*str + 9) & 0xf);
```

Which simplifies to:

```
result = (0) | ((*str + 9) & 0xf);
```

And again to:

```
result = (*str + 9) & 0xf;
```

Now let's look at the hex and binary representations of `a` - `f`:

```
a = 0x61 = 01100001
b = 0x62 = 01100010
c = 0x63 = 01100011
d = 0x64 = 01100100
e = 0x65 = 01100101
f = 0x66 = 01100110
```

After adding 9, the `& 0xf` operation clears out the top 4 bits, so we don't need to worry about those.  So we're effectively just adding 9 to the lower 4 bits.  In the case of `a`, the lower 4 bits are `1`, so adding 9 gives you `10`, and similarly for the others.

As chux mentioned in his comment, a more straightforward way of achieving this is as follows:

```
result = *str - 'a' + 10;
```

Comment: @FelixPalmen Not binary, apparently.  Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this was my first post so apologies if my question wasn't clear. Think I annoyed some people!